# Does React Native production app contain devDependencies?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-hermes

I faced the following issue https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library/issues/955. Production build is failed and error points to the library from devDependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from Satyajit Sahoo on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/u2ulh0/comment/i4lepbw/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

> The app contains what you import. Doesn't matter if it's in dependencies, devDependencies or you just created a file. Those fields are to tell npm/Yarn about what to install. Bundling looks only at your imports.
>
> If your bundle contains code from testing library`, then you're importing it into some file that's imported by your entry point.